# Use constants in swagger annotation

Tags: php, swagger, php-5.3, swagger-php

I have the following code : 
in `/lib/App/Vendor/bin` I created a file : `constants.php` with a define
`define('AUTH', 'test');` Now when I tried to execute `php swagger --boostrap constants.php`

I get the error :

`Scanning files in '/lib/App/Vendor/bin' ...[INFO] Required @SWG\Info() not found`

I don't understand where is the problem. Please help me ! Thx in advance ! Help me please...Somebody now the problem ??

```
/**
* @SWG\Swagger(
*     schemes={"http","https"},
*     host=AUTH,
*     basePath="/",
*     @SWG\Info(
*         version="0.1",
*         title="Api's ",
*     ),
* )
*/
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet with your swagger annotation?

Comment: @cen I edited the question

Comment: If you replace AUTH with a string constant, does it work?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use constants like that but I could be wrong. I googled for "swagger dynamic host" and there are some solutions apparently.

Comment: `--boostrap` is not valid argument, try `--bootstrap`